# Using the with clause in cursors in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a table emp(eid, ename, bossid, eloc) my requirement is to write a procedure to display all the employees and their boss name of all the employees who are located in the same location as per the given arguments (of a given emp id).  The above query can be simply solved (for eid=10) using "with" clause as below

```
with t (id, name, loc, bsid, bsname) as 
    (select a.eid, a.ename, a.eloc, b.eid, b.ename
     from emp a, emp b 
     where a.bossid = b.eid)
select y.id, y.bsname
from t x, t y
where x.loc = y.loc and  <b> x.id = 10;
```

but when I write a DB2 procedure as below the procedure fails to compile with error as "SQL0104N  An unexpected token "as" was found following "bsid, bsname)"."

```
create or replace procedure test with (
    in argid varchar(100),
)
LANGUAGE SQL
COMMIT ON RETURN NO
BEGIN
    for rec as (
        with t (id, name, loc, bsid, bsname)  as
                (select a.eid, a.ename, a.eloc, b.eid, b.ename
                 from emp a, emp b
                 where a.bossid = b.eid)
        select y.id, y.bsname
        from t x, t y
        where x.loc = y.loc and x.id = **argid**)
    do
        call dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || rec.id || ', Name = ' || rec.bsname );
    end for;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is your actual procedure code: `procedure test with (` and `**argid**` look very suspect.

If it is, then you should not be using parentheses around the SELECT statement in the FOR:

```
BEGIN
  for rec as -- parenthesis removed (
    with t (id, name, loc, bsid, bsname)  as
    ...
    where x.loc = y.loc and x.id = **argid** -- parenthesis removed)
```